# Adding hash variables to clickTAG in adWords

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, google-ads-api, clicktag

I'm building a Flash banner (as3) for AdWords, but I can't find in their documentation whether it is possible to add hash or querystring variables to appear in the eventual target url when u are using a clickTAG. Ideally I would like to use both. For example, my banner has four input fields and I would like to build my target url thusly:

```
var base:String= "http://www.example.com";
var qs:String= "?one=" + input1.text + "&two=" + input2.text;
var hs:String= "#three=" + input3.text + "&four=" + input4.text;
var targetUrl:String= base + qs + hs;
flash.net.navigateToURL(new URLRequest(targetUrl), "_blank");
```

Is this possible with AdWords while using clickTAG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately AdWords doesn't allow this. It would make it possible to redirect to a url that wasn't checked by them.

Answer (score 0):

Clicktags are generally just an URL sent to the swf via the adserver/publisher. It may be the URL you need (`base` in your example), or it may be a publisher tracker that redirects to the final landing page. In the latter case, simply attaching a query string won't work.

It might be possible to piggy-back a URL or a query string on the tracker, but how this is done would vary depending on the kind of tracker (if any).

Comment: Thanks, I understand, but would you happen to know the specifics for AdWords? That's the only tracker I'm worried about in this case.